# trouble with memory releasing. after recreating an activity ~30 times i run out of memory

Tags: android, android-activity, out-of-memory

the activity im calling "recreate()" on contains a surfaceview in it's xml layout, and it looks like i'm having trouble releasing memory from the bitmapfactory used by the surfaceview.

each time i recreate it decodes 10 bitmaps each at about 5-10KB.

i tried setting all of my bitmaps to null and running system.gc before every recreation but that didn't help.

i'm just trying to recreate my surface view periodically but i can't find a better way than recreating the activity it's in.

is there a more effective way to reinitialize my surface view, and if not, can you tell me what's going on with my garbage collection from this logcat?

```
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.irksomesloth.botbreaker/com.irksomesloth.botbreaker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3740)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at com.irksomesloth.botbreaker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     ... 12 more
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     ... 23 more
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:379)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:409)
04-28 03:39:05.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at com.irksomesloth.botbreaker.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:30)
```

Comment: You need to figure out where all the memory is going.  Some tools are available to make that easier.  See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html and https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html .

Comment: i already did that. which is part of how i knew it was the bitmaps not releasing memory.

Comment: Excellent.  From the hprof or mat output, determine what the root object is that's holding it in memory.  If they're being held by an Activity, check to see if there are multiple instances of Activity.  I see you've accepted bitmap-purging as an answer; you may want to go through this exercise anyway to make sure that you haven't just upgraded a fast leak to a slow leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the bitmap recycle() function. You might also need to set the bitmap option to purgeable. Here is a snippet where I resize a bitmap and output to a JPEG:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();;
options.inPurgeable = true;

Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(input , 0, input.length, options);
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, true);

ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, blob);

// recycle the memory
original.recycle();
resized.recycle();
```